# Как создать notification из fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-notification, android-button

В приложении есть несколько фрагментов в каждом из которых есть кнопка для создания уведомлений, после создания уведомлений  нужно что-бы при нажатии на уведомление мы переходили в тот фрагмент из которого было создано это уведомление. Проблема в том что ни одно из найденных мною решений не работает. Вот код который я нашел, но он не работает по не понятным мне причинам:

```
 public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Resources res = this.getResources();

        // до версии Android 8.0 API 26
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);

        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                // обязательные настройки
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_cat)
                //.setContentTitle(res.getString(R.string.notifytitle)) // Заголовок уведомления
                .setContentTitle("Напоминание")
                //.setContentText(res.getString(R.string.notifytext))
                .setContentText("Пора покормить кота") // Текст уведомления
                // необязательные настройки
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.hungrycat)) // большая
                // картинка
                //.setTicker(res.getString(R.string.warning)) // текст в строке состояния
                .setTicker("Последнее китайское предупреждение!")
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setAutoCancel(true); // автоматически закрыть уведомление после нажатия

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Альтернативный вариант
        // NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, builder.build());
    }
```

Если кто-то работал с notification из fragment буду рад вашей помощи и советам.

Comment: Вы бы отправили хоть какой-нибудь код, так как вот так помогать сложно

Comment: ну у меня только нерабочий есть, и возможно не полный, могу скинуть конечно))

Comment: ну я конкретно про findviewbyid() хочу глянуть, а с оповещениями не помогу (((

Comment: У фрагмента нет метода `findViewById()` - нужно находить кнопку во `View` - контейнере при его создании (`view.findViewById()`). А с уведомлением сложнее - нужно передавать в экстра какой фрагмент открыть, в активности проверять и открывать этот фрагмент (если  в двух словах).

Comment: ну вот допустим мне удалось найти кнопку (@woesss ваш способ помог) но дальше у меня студия считает что setOnClickListener это недостижимая константа. Это тоже все зависит от того что я в fragment работаю? потому-что в обычной активити все работает чудесно.

Comment: Ну это уже надо видеть - как-то неправильно применяете

Comment: то есть мой код все-так неверный получается))